# how can I calculate totals within a query, depending on the date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Below you can see my query, which gives the following result:

```
select t.actual_date, 
   t.id_key, 
   t.attendance_status, 
   t.money_step, 
   sum(t.money_step) over (partition by t.id_key order by t.actual_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)as accumulated
from example t
order by t.id_key, t.actual_date
```

[image: Results of the query]

I want the "accumulated" column to add up the value of "money_step" for each id_key.
If the attendance_status is the second time '15' for an Id, the counter should add up from the beginning. For ID_KEY = 1 it should look like this:

accumulated:

```
Row 1:20
Row 2: 80
Row 3: 100
Row 4: 120
```

How can I do this in the query? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to reset the sum after the first row where `attendance_status` has value `15`. One option uses a conditional `max()` to define the subgroup:

```
select 
    actual_date, 
   id_key, 
   attendance_status, 
   money_step, 
   sum(t.money_step) over (
       partition by id_key, grp 
       order by actual_date
   ) as accumulated
from (
    select 
        e.*,
        max(case when attendance_status = 15 then 1 else 0 end) over(
            partition by id_key 
            order by actual_date 
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
        ) grp
    from example e
) e
order by id_key, actual_date
```